# Google Chrome Windows/iOS desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I am building a web app when the user finds a match, the app will deliver a desktop notification to the user. I am not sure if it can be achieved with HTML or JavaScript.

When there is a match, the web app will deliver a desktop notification similar to how Slack does it

[image]

Any idea how I would achieve this? Thanks

Comment: SO isn't really a tutorial site, so I think this question should be closed as it lacks clarity and the implementation/famework/language choice could be considered opinion based  - we need concrete examples of things you've tried in order to be able to assist. However, start researching here: [Push Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries like `react-notifications`(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications) and `vue-notifications` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-notification) can trigger these notifications programmatically.

In my experience, I used this when a DB has been updated, which triggered a function in my application and fired the notification.